# Desert plant looking like a stone / chunk of dried wood

Tags: identification, desert

I have seen both in a market and in a botanic garden a desert (?) plant which looks like a ball (20 cm diameter) of dried wood, with a lot of cracks/grooves, from the middle of which a small trunk (10cm) grows.
Do you know the name?

Comment: You got me curious now, do you have a picture by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not now... do you have any guess?

Comment: Desert plants that look like rock is usually Lithops, but with 20 cm diameter not!

Answer (score 1):

Found: Dioscorea Elephantipes !